# How to handle collisions in guava table?

Tags: java, guava

Assume that we have a MyBean class with simple *int count* field, and Guava table like this;

```
Table<Integer, Integer, MyBean> table; // we can instantiate like HashBasedTable.create();
```

I want to sum count fields, when i put a new MyBean object and this position has an existing MyBean object in table.

```
table.put(1, 1, new MyBean(1)); 
table.put(1, 1, new MyBean(2)); // so what will be going on ?
```

Actually this is a very simple case and I want to work on complex objects if they are in collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Table` behaves just like a `Map`, i.e., the second `put` overwrites the first. What you'd need is sort of `Multimap`. There's an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=902) for a `Multitable` already, vote for it.

Currently, you can either use a

```
Table<Integer, Integer, SomeCollection<MyBean>>
```

or a

```
Map<SomePair<Integer, Integer>, MyBean>
```

I'd recommend the latter, as composing keys is way simpler than dealing with the "multi" stuff.

---

If you're feeling really hacky today, you could even use

```
Map<Long, MyBean>
```

Just don't tell anybody it was me who proposed this. And encapsulate the hack properly, so you don't don't get bitten by some int to long automatic conversion somewhere.